# ascii in powershell (wscript.shell)

Tags: powershell, ascii

I'm creating a script that create shortcuts to our archiving drive.
I would like the filename to start with an Omega-sign; so windows always sorts it at the bottom.
The output of my script shows the omega sign; but the link that gets created changes this omega to O (capital O). 
Manually I can make a shortcut that starts with the omega sign, so it must be related to wscript.shell

relevant part of the script:

```
$locatie = $doel+"\Ω_archief "+$file.Name+".lnk"
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$ShortCut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($locatie)
$ShortCut.TargetPath=$file.Fullname
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: I think the Wscript.Shell object can't work with Unicode. You can try the following: Create the .lnk file with a temporary non Unicode name and then use Powershell to rename it to your Unicode name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `Save()` method in `WScript.Shell`'s shortcut object. It appears that this API call requires `ANSI` names to create the file, thus choking on characters out of `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default`.

However, here's a workaround: create a shortcut using well-distinguished `ANSI` name and then rename it as follows:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path  ### mcve
$doel = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Test"             ### mcve

$locatie = $doel+"\Ω_archief "+$file.Name+".lnk"

$locatieTemp = $locatie.Replace('\Ω_archief','\OMEGA_archief')
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$ShortCut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($locatieTemp)
$ShortCut.TargetPath=$file.Fullname
$Shortcut.Save()

if (Test-Path $locatie) { Remove-Item $locatie }

Move-Item -Path $locatieTemp $locatie

### or Rename-Item instead of Move-Item:
#      Rename-Item -Path $locatieTemp $(Split-Path $locatie -Leaf)
###
```

Note that the first two lines added to satisfy [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (mcve)  rules.

Comment: that's indeed how I did it; based on sunzi's answer. I marked yours as solution to be able to close it.